# Getting the indexes of duplicate elements in arrays (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, duplicates

I have an array in Ruby that has some duplicate elements. E.g.:

```
fruits = ["apples", "bananas", "apples", "grapes", "apples"]
```

When I do the following:

```
fruits.index("apples")
# returns 0
```

I only get the first occurrence of `"apples"` which is, in this case, `fruits[0]`. Is there a way that I can run something similar to the above code and get the indexes of the other occurrences of `"apples"`? If I can't run something similar to the above code, how else can I get the indexes of the duplicate elements?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry, I had meant to; simply forgot. Your answer was useful; thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking a page from procedural languages, we could write:

```
fruits.each_index.select { |i| fruits[i]=="apples" }
  #=> [0, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
fruits.to_enum.with_index.select{|e, _| e == "apples"}.map(&:last)
# => [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: The "_" just means the variable is not going to be used.

Comment: Note that `_` is indeed a variable: `_=3; puts _#=> 3`. Some prefer writing something like `|e,_ndx|`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = ["apples", "bananas", "apples", "grapes", "apples"]

p fruits.each_with_index.group_by{|f,i| f}.each{|k,v| v.map!(&:last)}
# => {"apples"=>[0, 2, 4], "bananas"=>[1], "grapes"=>[3]}
```